# Using this.mycanvas.clipRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) **outside** onDraw function

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I have a class called CustomCanvas that class extends View. Like the code below:
This class is part of an API I'm developing. In this context it was decided that all operations were carried out without relying on the onDraw by a performance decision.

```
public class CustomCanvas extends View {
 ...

public void clipRegionImage(int x, int y, int width, int height){
Rect rect = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
this.mycanvas.clipRect(rect, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    super.onDraw(canvas);
} 
...
}
```

I want to use the function `clipRegionImage(..)` without using the `canvas.clipRect` inside `onDraw`. When I try use the function I can't clip the image.

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, add "Canvas" as a parameter to the method `clipRegionImage`, then call the method inside `onDraw`.  You **have** to use the Canvas provided in `onDraw`.  It also is different every time so you shouldn't save it.

Comment: Canvas is not a paramter but an object. I have to use this.mycanvas      outside onDraw. 
   public CustomCanvas(int width, int height) {
    this.myCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }